# Is it possible to have two valid big O runtimes that depend on different variables?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science

Consider the subset sum problem where you are given a set of all positive integers and wish to determine the number of ways you could use a subset of them to obtain a desired value. Essentially, counting up the number of solutions to a coin change while only having one coin of each denomination. This algorithm (taken from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqlNzOcnCfs) computes this:

[image]

The author presented the run time as `O(n * total)` where `n` is the number of integers you can use to make up the sum (here n = 4) and total is the value you wish to sum to.

But in the worst case, the recursion can split at most twice in the last else statement and the depth of the recursion is at most `n`, so couldn't you also say that recursion tree has a maximum number of calls `O(2^n)` and this should be another valid runtime complexity? Is there a logical contradiction here since this big O does not depend on `total` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in the worst case, the recursion can split at most twice in the last else statement and the depth of the recursion is at most n, so couldn't you also say that recursion tree has a maximum number of calls O(2^n)

That would have been the case if it were not for this line at the top of the implementation:

```
if key in mem:
    return mem[key]
```

It is this line that prevents the code from going into that last `else` in cases when the return value for the same combination of `total` and `i` has been computed. There are at most `n * total` such combinations, so that is the limiting factor for computing big O(...) for the algorithm. This technique related to dynamic programming is called [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The timing you get in this situation is dependent on `total`, so the algorithm is [*pseudo-polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time).

Comment: Memoization makes things more efficient but the tree itself will still never be bigger than `O(2^n)`, if I am correct. So although saying that the runtime is `O(n * total)` is better, shouldn't my statement still hold?

Comment: @QuantumDot For `n` numbers of `k` bits each, where `k` is some fixed number, max `total` is n*2^k, giving O(n^2) because 2^k is constant. You could write that your algorithm is O(min(2^n, n*total)) if you wish to underscore that for inputs with small `n` the code could run faster than would be implied by `total`, but that's usually not required: you memoize things to get rid of 2^n.

Comment: "For n numbers of k bits each, where k is some fixed number, max total is n*2^k, giving O(n^2) because 2^k is constant." --- I'm not sure what you mean by this and what you're relating it to. And by "max total," do you mean the maximum value that `total` could be?

Comment: @QuantumDot That's right, I meant the maximum value of `total`.

Comment: But why are you representing `total` with multiple numbers of "k bits each"? How does that relate to the algorithm?

Comment: @QuantumDot `total` cannot exceed sum of all elements of `arr`, otherwise we know that the answer is "no" right, and exit before calling the function.

Comment: Alright. Another thing is that, although there are `n * total` combinations this only matters for runtime if each combination isn't repeated more than a constant number of times.. How do we know that's true?

Comment: @QuantumDot The same combination may be encountered any number of times, it's just that we do the work only the first time we see it; the second and subsequent times we encounter the same combination, we look up the result and go on without doing any additional work.

Comment: That may be true, but even when we encounter the same combination the function call will take constant time.

Comment: @QuantumDot Not only that, but it would also not go any deeper, so at the worst case we do as much work as it takes to fill out the `[n*total]` grid. That's the heart of the memoization technique.

Comment: However that doesn't mean it won't call the same, memoized combination many many times. Simply because there are `n * total` combinations doesn't mean they won't be called `n` times each, for instance. Clearly that doesn't happen but it certainly seems to me that our analysis is incomplete without bounding the number of times each is called.

Comment: @QuantumDot It does mean that you wouldn't see `n` calls for each pair, because you have at most `[n*total]` recursive invocations that call into function `dp`. If a value is in the table, there are no further calls from that branch of recursion, and the number of items that remain to be computed goes down by at least one. Computing a value is a one-way street - once the value is stored, we don't compute it again, so we wouldn't get more than 2*n*total calls of `dp` in the worst case, when each recursive call is exactly two levels deep.